# Regular expression with full match only

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I know that this hackneyed theme and I read related answers...
However, I will ask...
I have input string in next format:

```
3#0.01, 2#0.5, 1#-10, -2#~
```

So this is a list of values splitted by comma.
I can catch all values with next expression:

```
(([-+]?\d+)#([-+]?\d*\.?\d+|~))+
```

It's working fine.

But I want to have no matching if any mistake is presenting in input string, for example:

```
MISTAKE3#0.01, 2#0.5, 1#-10, -2#~AND_HERE_MISTAKE_TOO
```

Unfortunately ^ and $ symbols are not helping here.
So my question: how can I stop matching if some part of input string is invalid.
Thanks.

Here is snippet: **https://regex101.com/r/Xih0Qk/2**

Comment: Try `(([-+]?\b\d+)#([-+]?\d*\.?\d+|~\B))+`

Comment: Wiktor, thanks for your attempt. But, unfortunately, no.

Comment: So, you want to match them all only after validating the whole string? Something like https://regex101.com/r/Xih0Qk/3?

Comment: Wiktor, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Wiktor, wielkie dzięki, if I have guessed ;)

Comment: Is it in PHP? Because the pattern is only compatible with PCRE or Boost (and Python PyPi `regex` library). You do not usually have to cram all inside 1 pattern. Why do you want to have 1 pattern? What is the use case?

Comment: Wiktor, language is C#. I just want to validate and parse input string in one pattern. this is description for rounding

Comment: In C#, you may do it in a different way. Probably, the one I showed is the most efficient.

Comment: Wiktor, I prefer to use much more universal solutions. Probably I will do similar job in JS, so regex is more wanted than lanuage-specific features.

Comment: If you have access to the actual code, it can be done a bit nicer. Do you?

Comment: In JS, you will be able to do something like this ONLY if you use ECMAScript 2018 compatible regex engine (as is now used in Chrome). The one above won't work at all there.

Comment: Wiktor, yes I have access to code. "Nicer" is interesting word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET, you may use a regex with inifinite width lookbehinds (it is also supported in the latest ECMAScript 2018 powered JavaScript environments, if you need to port the same solution there). The regex will look like

```
(?<=^(?:[-+]?\d+#(?:[-+]?\d*\.?\d+|~),\s)*)[-+]?\d+#(?:[-+]?\d*\.?\d+|~)(?=(?:,\s[-+]?\d+#(?:[-+]?\d*\.?\d+|~))*$)
```

See the [online regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%28%3F%3A%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5Cd%2B%23%28%3F%3A%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B%7C%7E%29%2C%5Cs%29*%29%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5Cd%2B%23%28%3F%3A%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B%7C%7E%29%28%3F%3D%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cs%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5Cd%2B%23%28%3F%3A%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B%7C%7E%29%29*%5Cr%3F%24%29&i=3%230.01%2C%202%230.5%2C%201%23-10%2C%20-2%23%7E%0D%0AMISTAKE3%230.01%2C%202%230.5%2C%201%23-10%2C%20-2%23%7EAND_HERE_MISTAKE_TOO%0D%0A80%230.01%2C%20223%23.5%2C%207%23%2B15%2C%203%23%7E&o=m)

In code, it is easier to build the pattern from a variable:

```
var block = @"[-+]?\d+#(?:[-+]?\d*\.?\d+|~)";   // Block/unit pattern
var pattern = $@"(?<=^(?:{block},\s)*){block}(?=(?:,\s{block})*$)";
var results1 = Regex.Matches("3#0.01, 2#0.5, 1#-10, -2#~", pattern)
    .Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
if (results1.Count() > 0)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results1));
var results2 = Regex.Matches("MISTAKE3#0.01, 2#0.5, 1#-10, -2#~AND_HERE_MISTAKE_TOO", pattern)
    .Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
if (results2.Count() > 0)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results2));
```

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/mCeRG9). Output (only the right string matched):

```
3#0.01, 2#0.5, 1#-10, -2#~
```

**Pattern explanation**

- `(?<=^(?:{block},\s)*)` - a positive lookbehind that only matches a location immediately preceded with 0+ occurrences of a `{block}` pattern at the start of the string followed with a `,` and 1 whitespace
- `{block}` - your block/unit pattern to match
- `(?=(?:,\s{block})*$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with 0+ occurrences of a `,`, a whitespace and a `{block}` pattern up to the end of the string.

Comment: Wiktor, thanks! You are the best. Can I ask about small detail: how can I match only WRONG patterns. MISTAKE3#0.01, 2#0.5, 1#-10, -2#~AND_HERE_MISTAKE_TOO. First and last in this line, for example.

Comment: @SergeyAlikin Probably, if you remove all the valid ones, `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?:^|,\s)[-+]?\d+#(?:[-+]?\d*\.?\d+|~)(?=,\s|$)", "").Split(new[] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: Wiktor, thank you very very much. I will not disturb you more.